# Wrong VBA date format in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to print out different date formats in my Exel sheet using VBA. However, I can't seem to output the "yyyy-mm-dd" format, or the "mmm dd, yyyy" formats. The cells don't seem to print out the correct formats. For instance:

```
'Declare new date variables
Dim LongDateFmt As String
Dim ShortDateFmt As String
Dim MediumDateFmt As String
Dim NewDateFmt As String
'Change the date to the new submission date
    MediumDateFmt = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Range("A1").Value = MediumDateFmt
    LongDateFmt = Format(Date, "Long Date")
    Range("A2").Value = LongDateFmt
    ShortDateFmt = Format(Date, "Short Date")
    Range("A3").Value = ShortDateFmt
    NewDateFmt = Format(Date, "MMMM dd, yyyy")
    Range("A4").Value = NewDateFmt
```

A1 prints out 13/06/2013, A2 prints 13-Jun-13, A3 prints out 13/06/2013 and A4 prints 13-Jun-13 as well.

Is this a settings problem or is my code wrong?

Comment: The code works if the cells are set to `Text` format, otherwise it returns the results you reported. The `MediumDateFmt` etc. values are correctly set in your code.

Answer (score 4):

you ought to change the cell format and not use formatted strings

```
with Range("A1")
   .Value = Date
   .Numberformat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
end with
```

for instance

Answer (score 2):

`Format` doesn't set the format of a cell to what you want, it simply gives you a string of a specified format. Inserting that string into a cell won't necessarily give you the results you want since the current formatting of the cell may have an impact.

If you want to change formatting of *the cell itself,* you need to set its `NumberFormat` property, with something like:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```